# Testing Formik using enzyme and jest in react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, formik

My Formik page:

```
const IssueForm =({values,errors,touched,isSubmitting})=>{
   const [modified,setModified] = useState(false);
    const handleModified = () => setModified(true);
    const handleSubmit = () => setModified(false);
    return(
    <div><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
        <h1>Add Issue</h1><br></br>
        <Form>
            <div>
                <label>Description: </label>
                <Field width="100px" type="text" name="issueDescription" placeholder="issuedescription"  onInput={handleModified}/>
                {touched.issueDescription && errors.issueDescription&&<span style={{color:'red'}}>{errors.issueDescription}</span>}
            </div><div><br></br>
             
            <button  type ="submit" disabled={isSubmitting} onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
            
        </Form>
    </div>
    )
    };
```

I have mentioned one field .like this I have so many fields.
when I used normal form  I generated test cases successfully  as below.

```
describe('Test UserForm using Shallow rendering', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<UserForm/>);
    });

    it('has 1 text input elements', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('input').length).toEqual(1);
    })

    
    it('should allow to type in issuedescription input field', () => {
        wrapper.find('input#issueDescription').simulate('change', {
            target: {value: 'Sachin'}
        });
        wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper.find('input#issueDescription').prop('value')).toEqual('Sachin');
    })

    
});
```

when I changed my normal from to formik I executed the same test cases in formik I am getting error.
for first case :
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

```
Expected: 1
Received: 0
```

for second case:

Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

I need to run this two cases for formik page .Iam new to react .can anyone help??